# How do I discard user input delivered during sleep function?

Tags: c, input, stdin

I'm trying to create a game using the terminal. I ask if the player is ready and then make a countdown with the code down below. The problem is that all input the user makes is added to the next input query the program makes. I'm looking for a way to discard the previous input or block it entirely during this function.

I could do a getchar loop, but that would need user input after the countdown (pressing enter) which I don't want.

```c
void countdown(void){
  printf("5\n");
  sleep(1);
  printf("4\n");
  sleep(1);
  printf("3\n");
  sleep(1);
  printf("2\n");
  sleep(1);
  printf("1\n");
  sleep(1);
  clearScreen(0); //clears terminal
}
```

Comment: Look into [ncurses](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

Comment: if you are in windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit?view=vs-2017

Comment: Windows also implements the non-standard `fflush(stdin)` and `rewind(stdin)` both of which clear the input buffer, but are not portable.

Comment: @pmg I can't use ncurses because it implies an extra library that must be installed

Comment: And I'm working with linux mint and the program must run on CentOS

Comment: @WeatherVane is it safe to use fflush?

Comment: @bsheps only if it is documented thus, but it now seems the OS is Linux, so: no.

Comment: I'm reading about tcflush... sounds promising: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/tcflush.html

Comment: You  want to put the terminal into non-canonical mode: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Canonical-or-Not.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a linux environment, you can try using `tcflush()`

[Link to tcflush documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcflush.3p.html)

Here is a modified example of your code using tcflush. You can uncomment the bottom portion and see that everything entered during the countdown is cleared from the stdio buffer.

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main(){
        char str[100];
        printf("5\n");
        sleep(1);
        printf("4\n");
        sleep(1);
        printf("3\n");
        sleep(1);
        printf("2\n");
        sleep(1);
        printf("1\n");
        sleep(1);

        // arguments for tcflush: 
        // 0 is for stdin 
        // TCIFLUSH is to flush data received but not read
        tcflush(0,TCIFLUSH);

        // prove it works by uncommenting this code
//      printf("fgets is waiting");
//      fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
//      printf("%s", str);

//      clearScreen(0); //clears terminal
}
```

Comment: Note that `int main()` is required by ISO C, not void.  But yes, this works, even clearing the line-edit buffer (text you've typed but haven't pressed return on yet).

Answer (score 4):

You basically can't; The notion of "discarding user input during a certain amount of time" doesn't really make any sense for standard out- and input, consider the fact that your input might come from a file for instance (the problem here is that 'time' isn't really a concept that exists in any way in the standard in/output routines).

You'd need a terminal API for that, and there's nothing like that in the C standard library, although there are libraries that provide capabilities like that (but you already said you didn't want to use external libraries).

Comment: That makes sense, but is there a way to discard it just before exiting the function?

Comment: What about using tcflush?

Comment: @bsheps That's part of the linux terminal API, not standard C.

Comment: @Cubic In his comments below the question he says he's using linux mint and the program must run on CentOS. Wouldn't both of those (linux) environments have access to this library by default? (fyi- I'm still pretty new to C)

Comment: @bsheps this is more of a 'answer the question that was asked' rather than 'solve the underlying problem OP has' kind of answer

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a thread for the countdown.

The main code starts the countdown thread, then loops to get an input.

If the input function returns before the thread has terminated, or the wrong reply was entered, ignore the input and repeat the loop.

Comment: If you're going that approach there's really no need for a thread though; You could just replace the sleep function with a loop that discards input until a certain amount of time has passed.

Comment: @Cubic but wouldn't that require the user to put an input anyway?